# Prevent data loss from sqlite database onUpgrade

Tags: java, android

Right now my onUpgrade method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questions");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

This currently makes a new table everytime my app is updated from the market.

How can I prevent my table from being deleted and only being recreated or modified when I wanted to?

Answer (score 1):

You should check database versions. `onUpgrade()` is executed only if current version is older than the new one. Check if your subclass's of `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor every time passes the same parameter (last one). **In you case the database will not be recreated if your database version remains the same**, `onUpgrade(`) will not be executed.

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent my table from being deleted and only being recreated or modified when I wanted to?

Delete the current body of your `onUpgrade()` method and do a more sophisticated upgrade process: adding tables, dropping tables, altering tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

See this [solution](http://blog.arthurassuncao.com/2013/05/android-manter-dados-do-banco-de-dados.html) (in Portuguese):

Just create temporary tables with all data(backup), drop/create others database tables and copy(re-insert) temporary table data to new structure. A solution that works, but probably not in every case.